# Why auth service don't remember authentication?

Tags: typescript, angular2-services

I have an auth guard and auth service which work correctly. But when I trying to open my application in a new browser tab I'm not logged in. My app required the login from me again. I think auth service must remember me while application doesn't restart, but isn't work. How to change this for remembering me without entering login and password for each new tabs?

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private loggedIn = false;

  get isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  login(user: User) {
    this.loggedIn = true;
    window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.router.navigate(['/vds-list']);
  }

  logout() {
    this.loggedIn = false;
    window.localStorage.clear();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    console.log(state.url);
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login'], {
        queryParams: {
          accessDenied: true
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
  }

  canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.canActivate(childRoute, state);
  }
}
```

I have a `loggedIn` variable and `isLoggedIn` method must return `true` after successful authentication once, but its work only for the same tab, unfortunately. Or other words why `AuthService#loggedIn` is `false` but I'm authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the `user` from localStorage first, in new tabs (or page refreshes).

Try adding this to constructor of `AuthService`:

```
try {
  let userJson = window.localStorage.getItem('user');
  let user = JSON.parse(userJson);
  this.isLoggedIn = !!user;
} catch (e) {
  // no user
}
```

Comment: yes I thought about this solution, but if anyone set any random value into localStorage with 'user' key then he gets access to the system. Or I think don't correctly and its doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, it does. BUT! You should NEVER trust frontend in your system. Even without localStorage, they can just mock the data. If this is important, you can share some data via a session cookie or similar, or jwt token, or some specific header. Regardless of what, you still ALWAYS re-verify this token at backend. So, you can store, instead of the whole `user` object, just his `authToken`, ``jwtToken`, `authorizationHeader` or similar. Or set a cookie and ignore auth in your app, let browser handle it. If the request is unauthenticated, backend redirects user to auth page,otherwise, browser sets it